Get data from Datalogger via wget/curl
I need to download the data from a datalogger, day by day, which only allows ftp/wget/curl. I need to create a script which download the files from the folder (or the folder itself) day by day every 10minutes.
The structure is: IP-Address/data/date (e.g.240615) as a folder/e.g. int_magnetek_240615.txt/
Looks like this: 192.168.30.240/data/240615/int_magnetek_240615.txt
The problem is i can only download 1 file and every day the name of the folder (for ex. 240615 to 240616) change will change.
I also tried to use the mirror function without success.
This is my script for a successful download (but only 1 file and only if i specify the folder and file)
#!/bin/bash
exec > >(tee -i update_logfile.txt)
exec 2>&1
today="$(date +'%d%m%Y')"
printf "Record load started: %s\n" "$today"
echo "get records"
wget -m -N --user='username' --password='password' 192.168.30.240/data/240615/int_magnetek_240615.txt -P /home/username/upload

Is someone able to help me please?
I tried several scripts but no success. I must also specify the foldername and the textfile, otherwise it fails.

You say you want to download a file from a folder whose name looks like 240615 which appears to be YYMMDD format. So in your code you get the current date in a variable named today using today="$(date +'%d%m%Y')", i.e. in DDMMYYYY format instead of YYMMDD, and then you use a hard-coded date of 240615 in your curl command, not attempting to use the today variable you just created at all. It seems like there's some opportunities there for you to make some progress yourself before asking for help.

what is the significance of "every 10minutes" ?

The file must be sent to another file server every 10 minutes during the day, as the collected data continues to be written to this file.

and what does "i can only download 1 file" mean? if you can only download it once, how can you also download it every 10 minutes?
